# SQLAlchemy "imperative mapping" many to many relationship

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have two tables, Students and Courses. I am trying to create a many to many relationship between these two entities using SQLAlchemy imperative mapping style but I could not find any examples.

Below is my two tables:

```
student_table = Table(
    'student',
    metadata,
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column('name', String(50)),
    Column('course_id', String(255), ForeignKey('course.id')
)

course_table = Table(
    'course',
    metadata,
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column('name', String(50)),
    Column('student_id', String(255), ForeignKey('student.id')
)

mapper_registry.map_imperatively(
    Student, 
    student_table, 
    properties (
        'course': relationship (
                Course,
                backref='student'
        )
    )
)

mapper_registry.map_imperatively(
    Course, 
    course_table, 
    properties (
        'course': relationship (
                Student,
                backref='course'
        )
    )
)

@dataclass
class Student:
    id: int 
    name: str 
    course_id: str

@dataclass
class Course:
    id: int 
    name: str 
    student_id: str
```

This is not working for me, anyone shed lights on how to implement many to many relationship with imperative mapping styles?

I tried to create a many to many relationship using imperative styles but couldn't achieve any working examples

Comment: For a many-to-many relationship you need an [association table](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/basic_relationships.html#many-to-many).

Comment: To define a relationship between **Students** and **Courses** declare an asociation table (`Table`) that contain each column by parent-child or student-class, be aware to not write as confusing and try to follow that pattern to your "Parent" class.

Answer (score 1):

You are not just mapping imperatively, but also [mapping dataclasses](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/dataclasses.html#mapping-dataclasses-using-declarative-with-imperative-table), which means you're supposed to use a slightly different syntax.

Then for [many-to-many](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/basic_relationships.html#many-to-many) relationship, you need an association table.

Putting together those two with your code, this is what I propose.

First mapping each dataclass, with an imperative table `__table__` and including a relationship via `__mapper_args__` through the `secondary` table (note, it is a string for late evaluation as I defined it after the dataclasses, if defining first you can use the variable directly).

Then create the association table like in the docs.

```py
from __future__ import annotations

from dataclasses import dataclass, field

from sqlalchemy import (
    Column,
    ForeignKey,
    Integer,
    String,
    Table,
    create_engine,
)
from sqlalchemy.orm import registry, relationship

mapper_registry = registry()


@mapper_registry.mapped
@dataclass
class Student:
    __table__ = Table(
        "student",
        mapper_registry.metadata,
        Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True),
        Column("name", String(50)),
    )

    id: int = field(init=False)
    name: str
    courses: list[Course] = field(default_factory=list)

    __mapper_args__ = {
        "properties": {
            "courses": relationship(
                "Course",
                secondary="course_student_association_table",
                back_populates="students",
            )
        }
    }


@mapper_registry.mapped
@dataclass
class Course:
    __table__ = Table(
        "course",
        mapper_registry.metadata,
        Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True),
        Column("name", String(50)),
    )

    id: int = field(init=False)
    name: str
    students: list[Course] = field(default_factory=list)

    __mapper_args__ = {
        "properties": {
            "students": relationship(
                "Student",
                secondary="course_student_association_table",
                back_populates="courses",
            )
        }
    }


course_student_association_table = Table(
    "course_student_association_table",
    mapper_registry.metadata,
    Column("course_id", ForeignKey("course.id"), primary_key=True),
    Column("student_id", ForeignKey("student.id"), primary_key=True),
)

engine = create_engine("sqlite://", future=True, echo=True)

mapper_registry.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

This emits

```sql
CREATE TABLE student (
        id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
        name VARCHAR(50), 
        PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE course (
        id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
        name VARCHAR(50), 
        PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE course_student_association_table (
        course_id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
        student_id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
        PRIMARY KEY (course_id, student_id), 
        FOREIGN KEY(course_id) REFERENCES course (id), 
        FOREIGN KEY(student_id) REFERENCES student (id)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, set up an association table:

```
assoc_table = Table(
    "association",
    metadata,
    Column('id', int, primary_key=True),
    Column('student_id', int, ForeignKey('student.id')),
    Column('course_id', int, ForeignKey('course.id'))
)
```

Then, add the relation to the association table. I think you only have to add this once, the `backref` attr makes sure you have access to the relationship both ways:

```
mapper_registry.map_imperatively(
    Student, 
    student_table, 
    properties (
        'course': relationship(Course,secondary=assoc_table, backref='students')
    )
```